Is there any analogue of moduli space of bundles for graphs ? (Generalization of Sandpile/Jacobian group = rank 1 bundles)
Graphs might be seen as "tropical degenerations" of algebraic curves, and analogue of Jacobian for algebraic curves is played by the "Sandpile" group - which is just the cokernel of Laplacian. That have been studied a lot recent years, see e.g. nice slides by one of the inventors: "Secret Life of Graphs" Matt Baker, or section 3: "The critical group of a graph" in R.Stanley review, or Mathoverflow "Sandpile".
Jacobian is moduli space of line (rank = 1 ) bundles on the curves.
Question 1: Are there any works/ideas on generalisation to higher ranks - what  can be moduli space of vector bundles for  graphs ? What nice properties one may expect ?
Formulas relating "motive" of Bun G to Jacobian - like for curves ? Hitchin system on cotangent bundle ? Geometric Langlands ?
I am only aware of my colleagues works on some analogues of rank 2 bundles:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.11584
"Graph potentials and symplectic geometry of moduli spaces of vector bundles"
Pieter Belmans, Sergey Galkin, Swarnava Mukhopadhyay
